# Are there any WAPs out there that support fiber optic daisy chaining?

Tags: wifi, fiber

This may not even be possible, but it seems like it would be the best way to do this, so I'll ask. Basically I'm wanting to string together wireless access points with fiber. I'm already having a hard enough time finding a fiber based WAP, but I'm also looking for daisy chaining if that can be done.

Any ideas?

Comment: fiber + daisy chain = FDDI :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you need an Ethernet switch with fiber ports, or some fiber to copper media converters and a switch, along with an access point. Finding an access point with a switch and fiber ports on the device is going to be *very* expensive, if anything like that is even manufactured by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that most enterprise wireless access points are designed to use POE and so won't have an SFP interface on them.  Many do, however, have 2 10/100/1000 interfaces and bridge the two together so you can have your APs chained together as you're describing, but via copper twisted pair.

What are you looking for that you wouldn't achieve using a small switch or a media converter next to the AP?

Comment: I just want to use fiber in this environment (although it may not be 100% necessary, I think it would be better) and was looking for a solution that was all in one package.

Answer (score 0):

What you will probably need is a transceiver similar to [this one](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=084650).
[image: canary transceiver]